# How to use marker shape and color from different columns

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, errorbar

I have a dataframe with 6 columns; x, xerr, y, yerr, class, asses

the column class has only 4 different entries ( A, B, C or D) and column asses also have 4 different entries (Good, Bad, Danger, Okay).

I am trying to make an errorbar plot where the colors of the marker will be based on the entries from column class, and the marker shape will be based on the entries from column asses.

I tried this but fails, not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(2023) # to make consistent reproducible sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.rand(10),
                     'xerr': np.random.rand(10),
                     'y': np.random.rand(10),
                     'yerr': np.random.rand(10),
                     'class': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B'],
                     'asses': ['Good', 'Bad', 'Danger', 'Okay', 'Good', 'Bad', 'Danger', 'Okay', 'Good', 'Bad']})

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
marker_color = {'A': 'blue', 'B': 'red', 'C': 'green', 'D': 'orange'}
marker_shape = {'Good': 'd', 'Bad': 'o', 'Danger': '^', 'Okay': 's'}
for cls in df['class'].unique():
    class_mask = (df['class'] == cls)
    plt.errorbar(df['x'][class_mask], df['y'][class_mask],
                 xerr=df['xerr'][class_mask], yerr=df['yerr'][class_mask],
                 c=marker_color[cls], fmt=marker_shape[df['asses'][class_mask].iloc[0]],
                 label=cls)

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: From your data, all 'A's are 'Good', so should be blue and diamonds, all 'B's are 'Bad' and should be red and circles, and so on... right? That is the plot which appears to be drawn up. What is the issue? Can you explain what you mean by "I tried this but fails"? Are you getting an error, because the code ran fine for me